# How to send attachments with Infobip Email API?

Tags: infobip, infobip-api

I'm trying to send email message to multiple receivers with attachments trough Infobip. Because Infobip Email API doesn't support sending email to multiple receivers I'm sending email with RestSharp and I have stuck with how to send attachments.

Here is my code.

```
var client = new RestClient($"{configuration.BasePath}/email/3/send")
                {
                    Timeout = -1
                };

                string encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
                               .GetBytes(_configuration.UserName + ":" + _configuration.Password));

                var emailMessage = request.EmailMessage;
                if (emailMessage == null)
                    throw new Exception("EMAIL_MESSAGE_NOT_DEFINED");

                var restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

                restRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Basic {encoded}");
                restRequest.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
                restRequest.AddParameter("from", $"{request.EmailMessage.SenderEmailAddress}");

                foreach(var item in emailMessage.To.DefaultIfEmpty())
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Name))
                    {
                        restRequest.AddParameter("to", item.EmailAddress);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        restRequest.AddParameter("to", item.EmailAddress);
                    }
                }

                foreach (var item in emailMessage.Cc.DefaultIfEmpty())
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Name))
                    {
                        restRequest.AddParameter("cc", item.EmailAddress);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        restRequest.AddParameter("cc", item.EmailAddress);
                    }
                }

                foreach (var item in emailMessage.Bcc.DefaultIfEmpty())
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Name))
                    {
                        restRequest.AddParameter("bcc", item.EmailAddress);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        restRequest.AddParameter("bcc", item.EmailAddress);
                    }
                }

                if(emailMessage.InReplyTo != null)
                    restRequest.AddParameter("replyTo", emailMessage.InReplyTo.EmailAddress);

                restRequest.AddParameter("subject", emailMessage.Subject);
                restRequest.AddParameter("text", emailMessage.Text);

                if(emailMessage.IsHtml)
                    restRequest.AddParameter("html", emailMessage.Html);


                foreach(var attachment in emailMessage.Attachments.DefaultIfEmpty())
                {
                    restRequest.AddFile(attachment.Name, attachment.FileContent, attachment.Name);
                    restRequest.AddParameter("attachment", $"@files/{attachment.Name}");
                }
```

After execution I receive error:

```
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'attachment'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile' for property 'attachment[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Which class in C# language should I use instead of 'org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile' in Java?

Answer (score 0):

In InfoBip documentation is wrong example. It shouldn't be

`restRequest.AddParameter('attachment', ...);`

but

```
foreach (var file in files){
 byte[] testFile = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
 restRequest.AddFile("attachment", testFile, file);
}
```